# add username and password in post url with basic authentication (Json)

Tags: json, url, post, body-parser, jasonette

I want to add username and password in post url with basic authentication

http://IPaddress:port/F1/Details
{
Body
}

Answer (score 1):

Your not specified the programming language but if you are using c# it will be like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
        client.PostAsync("http://IPaddress:port/F1/Details", yourcontent);
```

Using Postman
[image]

Comment: thank u but i want to use it without put it in user/password's case soething like :   http://IPaddress:port/F1/Details/user/password..

Comment: you can post them with parameters like http://IPaddress:port/F1/Details?username=test&password=pass and update the Action in the controller to receive them.

Comment: Post : http://162.15.44.25:8080/interfaces/inventory/getDetails?username=admin&password=Mypassword